# MailMessage.Body Max Size

Tags: c#

Does anyone know what the max size the body attribute of a MailMessage can be?
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't mention anything on the size limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Body` is of type `string`. `string.Length` is declared as an `int`. Therefore, the (theoretical) maximum size is that of an `int`.. which is `2,147,483,647`.

That being said.. you'll likely run into size issues in the CLR/process itself before reaching that limit.